# Grails GORM rarely works in domain classes

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have many to many relationship between User and Organization. I want to delete user from all his organizations when the user is being deleted, so this is basically what I came up with:

```
class User {
    ...

    def beforeDelete() {
        def user = User.get(id)
        Organization.all.each {
            it.removeFromMembers(user)
            it.save()
        }
    }
}
```

This surprisingly doesn't work because `User.get(id)` returns null even though the user with the given id is in the database, when I look at the log, no sql statement is even executed.
So I tried to use `load()` method insted. ObjectNotFoundException is the result then. So I tried this as I was quite desperate:

`def user = User.find("from User as u where u.id = ?", [1L])`

This, for some reason, works. But now, the line with `it.removeFromMembers(user)` throws NullPointerException.

I tried to put this logic in my UserController and it works!

Why is this? Why can't I do this in domain classes? This makes `beforeDelete` hook (and all the others too) pretty useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first be sure to read the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) regarding the delete event. You can see that for any change to actually be reflected in the DB you need a new session, and since inside the event you are already working with the current object to be deleted, you don't need to call the `get()` method:

```
def beforeDelete() {
  User.withNewSession {
     organizations.each{ org -> 
        org.removeFromMembers(this)
     }
     this.save()
  }
}
```

(above code has not been tested)

The reason why you have null in the `get()` method is because `id` does not exist when the event is fired. If you want access to the id, you must retrieve it form the current object: `this.id`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it doesn't work. It throws an exception with this message: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.redhat.theses.auth.User#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.redhat.theses.auth.User#1]

Comment: maybe you need to call `this.merge()` before the `save()`, as stated in my answer, the code has not been tested, is just a reference to let you know that is possible to do that in the domain =)

Comment: Yes, I understand. As for this.merge() before this.save(), that doesn't work either, same exception :(